# CachedNetworkImage is stuck in progress state

Tags: flutter, dart

According to the documentation, an http call during widgets test will fail with a 400 status code.

So why the code below never displays the errorWidget ? However it displays the progressWidget and gets stuck there.

```
  testWidgets('Cached networked image 400', (tester) async {
    final widget = CachedNetworkImage(
      imageBuilder: (
        context,
        url,
      ) =>
          Container(
        key: Key('image'),
      ),
      progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, progress) => Container(
        key: Key('progress'),
      ),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(
        key: Key('failed'),
      ),
      imageUrl: 'https://example.com/image.png',
    );
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQueryData(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: widget,
        ),
      ),
    );

    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    expect(find.byKey(Key('progress')), findsOneWidget); // this should be findsNothing but why does it pass here?
    expect(find.byKey(Key('failed')), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.byKey(Key('image')), findsNothing);
```

I am getting:

> Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
>   Actual: _KeyFinder:] (ignoring offstage widgets)>

The plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

Comment: I gave your test a shot, actually I think it should fail when pumping the widget, but it doesn't, I don't  understand why. See: https://www.reddit.com/r/dartlang/comments/ikl0q0/execution_flow_interrupted_in_a_trycatch_block/